# How to fix "Invalid mapping expression parameter specified" in Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, restful-url, query-string

As you can see, I tried to set a simple query param called 'name'.

TBH, I don't fully understand what does "Mapped from" mean, [I just followed the official example document here (step 7)](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html#api-gateway-create-resource-and-methods) and set it to `method.request.querystring.name`. However it is still complaining that it is not valid.
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've just tried this and before you can add it under the "Integration Request" you have to add it under the "Method Request" (the one before the "Integration Request" in the visual flow for the method). I believe this is actually step 6 in the page you linked.